# How to make add break after paragraph in WhatsApp share on websites?

Tags: html, share, whatsapp

I am trying to give the following output with Share on WhatsApp from a website:

```
This is a sentence. 
This is another sentence.
```

with the following code:

```
<a href="whatsapp://send?text=This is a sentence. 
This is another sentence." data-action="share/whatsapp/share">Share on WhatsApp</a>
```

But it gives output as:

```
This is a sentence. This is another sentence.
```

How do I get it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try [encoding your string](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp). The character that you are probably looking for is `LF line feed`, which corresponds to `%0A`. Maybe something like this:

```
This%20is%20a%20sentence.%0AThis%20is%20another%20sentence.
```